# Method group in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, method-group

James Michael Hare recently wrote a [blog post](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2012/10/04/c.net-little-wonders-static-char-methods.aspx) about `Char` static methods. He talks about using a *method group* to write less-wordy LINQ:

```
if (myString.Any(c => char.IsLower(c))) { xyzzy(); }
if (myString.Any(char.IsLower)) { xyzzy(); } // Less wordy FTW!
```

The equivalent in VB.NET would be:

```
If myString.Any(Function(c) Char.IsLower(c)) Then xyzzy()
If myString.Any(Char.IsLower) Then xyzzy() 'Compiler error
```

Sadly, I can't do the equivalent of C# here... the compiler tells me that `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IsLower' accepts this number of arguments`... sadness. I thought it might be caused by me having `Option Strict` on, but alas, that didn't work either.

I'm assuming *method groups* aren't availablet in VB.NET... Is there a similar feature available in VB.NET? Or any particular reason why this can't (won't) be done in VB.NET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent VB code would be:

```
If myString.Any(AddressOf Char.IsLower) Then xyzzy()
```

Comment: Darn, looks a bit less scary then the `Function(c) DoSomethingWith(c)` mess, but not much shorter. Any idea how AddressOf works with overloads? It seems like each of the overloads for `Char.IsLower` would be at different addresses, but the code says no... (I'll probably ask this as a separate question since I'm not having much luck finding an answer).

Comment: @JeffBridgman Honestly, I'd suggest just learning the lambda syntax, it is very powerful.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Only the `IsLower(char c)` fits the predicate delegate `Func(Of TSource, Boolean))` of `Any` when `TSource` is `Char`

Comment: @Magnus Good point, that makes it nice and static again... and of course you can never have overloads with identical parameters so it can *always* "know" ;)