# How can I use the following AutoMapper generic method in VB.NET (without executing the method): Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

This is my first question here so please go easy on me ;-)

I am taking [a course on Udemy to learn ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-aspnet-mvc-5-course/). This course is being taught using C# but I have been following along using VB.NET. Right about half-way through the course, the instructor introduces a [library called AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for mapping domain objects to DTOs (data transfer objects).

**The C# code I am having trouble with:**

[`return _context.Customers.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>);`](https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vidly-mvc-5/commit/ca3f33561136a7b97f2f15a158e246a3d1bff3fe#diff-a99198a9febf1da7df640639126accdbR24)

**In VB.NET I believe it should be:**

`Return _context.Customers.ToList().[Select](Mapper.Map(Of Customer, CustomerDto))`

**However I am receiving the following errors:**

[image]

- `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Map' accepts this number of arguments.`

[image]

- `Overload resolution failed because no accessible '[Select]' can be called with these arguments:
  Extension method 'Public Function [Select](Of TResult)(selector As Func(Of Customer, TResult)) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'Enumerable': Type parameter 'TResult' cannot be inferred.`

[image]

**The signature of the AutoMapper function being called:**

**VB.NET**

`Public Shared Function Map(Of TSource, TDestination)(source As TSource) As TDestination`

**C#**

`public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source);`

It would appear that while C# allows omitting the `(TSource source)` parameter, VB.NET is requiring the same parameter `(source As TSource)`

Comment: I'm no fan of VB but, if `Of Customer`, why not also `Of CustomerDto`? They're both generic arguments...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it. Adding a second 'Of' clause on the CustomerDto type parameter causes a new error: " Keyword does not name a type "

Comment: There's no need for Select, you can just call Map and pass Customers.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu could you give an example of this? I need to return an IEnumerable(Of CustomerDto) mapped to Customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# construct being used here is called a [Method Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c).

The construct without a method group in C# would be to use a lambda expression, like this:

```
list.Select(c => Mapper.Map<Customer,CustomerDto>(c))
```

Which translates to VB.Net as follows:

```
list.Select(Function(c) Mapper.Map(Of Customer, CustomerDto)(c))
```

You can achieve something similar to the C# method group in VB.Net with the [`AddressOf` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803897/method-group-in-vb-net):

```
list.Select(AddressOf Mapper.Map(Of Customer, CustomerDto))
```

Comment: Holy moly that was fast! Thank you so much!! I spent quite a bit of time on this yesterday. I will now spend some time learning about the Method Group construct as I've been really having a hard time wrapping my mind around what's going on. Thanks again! :-)